# Using react-toolbox with reactGo

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, react-toolbox, reactgo

I'm using [reactGo](https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo) as a boilerplate for a web app and I'd like to include [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/#/) for the UI.  Through some unfruitful experimentation I have made at least some progress on including it in the project.  I'm getting hung up on the development server rendering. Since reactGo is isomorphic/universal (don't really care about the semantics anymore) it tries to load in the react-toolbox during Webpack's server compilation.  The problem is react-toolbox is build using CSS Modules.  Webpack 2 can handle CSS Modules but I'm getting caught up somewhere.  Any input would be extremely helpful.

webpack/rules/index.js:

```js
const image = require('./image');
const javascript = require('./javascript');
const css = require('./css');
const reactToolbox = require('./reactToolbox');

module.exports = ({ production = false, browser = false } = {}) => (
  [
    javascript({ production, browser }),
    css({ production, browser }),
    image(),
    reactToolbox()
  ]
);
```

webpack/rules/reactToolbox.js

```js
const PATHS = require('../paths');

module.exports = ({ production = false, browser = false } = {}) => {

  const browserSettings = [
    "style-loader",
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        modules: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]"
      }
    },
    "postcss-loader" // has separate config, see postcss.config.js nearby
  ];

  const serverSettings = [
    'isomorphic-style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader/locals',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: "[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]"
      }
    },
    "postcss-loader"
  ];

  return {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: [PATHS.modules + '/react-toolbox/'],
    use: browser ? browserSettings : serverSettings
  };
};
```

I've add the "isomorphic-style-loader" to help with the issues I was having with style-loader and it seems to have helped.  However I'm still stuck on getting the "css-loader/locals" to do it 's job correctly.

Any time I include a component from the react-toolbox library I end up with with an error along the lines of:

```js
/Project/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/theme.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :root {
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Project/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/index.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Project/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/button/index.js:20:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Project/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/app_bar/index.js:14:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

I've been pushing through on this one for a while now and I need some outside perspective.  Any input would be helpful. Don't be afraid to ask for more background info or code if you think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :
first, you dont need an extra reactToolbox.js in rules, just put the code of postcss.config in the css.js file.
Then in the return function of css.js add the path for node_modules in the include(PATHS.modules)
.
I made a extra file scss.js but it not mandatory.

Install the missing modules(csspost-nested,...)
And that's it, it work great :)

Comment: Could you post code example of how you did it please?

Answer (score 0):

Follow:
https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox#usage-in-webpack-projects-not-create-react-app

And add PATHS.modules to the return in css.js
`return {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: browser ? browserLoaders : serverLoaders,
    include: [PATHS.app, PATHS.modules]
  };`